What are the characters in this poem and what do they mean?
This is a poem on a certificate.  What are the characters and what do they mean?
Thanks!


It is not a poem, they are four slogans
堅強意志 - Strong will
不懈毅力 - Unrelenting perseverance
謙虛謹慎 - Modesty and prudence
嚴守紀律 - Strictly observe discipline
It sounds like an oath for a disciplined force (紀律部隊) like an army, police, or firefighters. "Strictly observe discipline" is a dead giveaway

Thank you so much!  It is on a martial arts certificate

If it is for martial artists, 嚴守紀律 (Strictly observe discipline) is the wrong choice of words.  it should be 嚴於律己 or 律己以嚴 (Strictly observe self-discipline )

would "Maintain strict observance of the laws of your discipline" be an accurate translation of it the way it is written?

" Strictly observe self-discipline" refers to upholding one's moral standards, not just obeying the rules and restraint applied to him; which is the classic definition of 嚴守紀律 (Strictly observe discipline)
